# call a function in mounted from methods in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

my problem is that i have to calculate all the coordinates around a specific point (that came from an API call tomtom).

the function in mounted in the following one:

```
ttSearchBox.on("tomtom.searchbox.resultselected", function (event) {
      var result = event.data.result;
      var position = result.position;

      resultLat.value = `${position.lat}`;
      resultLong.value = `${position.lng}`;

      console.log(resultLat.value, resultLong.value);
      return this.Haversine(resultLat.value, resultLong.value);
    });
```

while the function that i want to call is:

```
  Haversine(centerLat, centerLng) {
      // Ciclo per generare tutte le possibili coordinate nel raggio di 20 km
      for (let lat = centerLat - 0.2; lat <= centerLat + 0.2; lat += 0.001) {
        for (let lng = centerLng - 0.2; lng <= centerLng + 0.2; lng += 0.001) {
          const distance = this.getDistanceFromLatLng(
            centerLat,
            centerLng,
            lat,
            lng
          );
          if (distance <= 100) {
            this.coordinates.push({
              lat: +lat.toFixed(4),
              lng: +lng.toFixed(4),
            });
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(this.coordinates);
    },
  },
```

i want to call the function Haversine and i expet that it  will print in the console an array with all the coordinates

Comment: It's unclear what is the problem

Comment: It’s not easy to help here. Please consider providing a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example